# d3.js: synchronized brush selection over multiple charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have 4 different chart. If i brush on the area chart which is the first chart in this example I want that all the other charts which are under the area chart get zoomed in the region which is brushed on the area chart.

I added you [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lnz7c36e/19/) which is not in d3.js

does someone have an approach how to archive that? In best case with some resources.

My charts getting rendered dynamically because the amount of charts is variable.

Here my code:

```js
var signalData = {
  signal1: {
    name: "signal1",
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6],
  },
  signal2: {
    name: "signal2",
    data: [6, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 5, 7, 1],
  },
  signal3: {
    name: "signal3",
    data: [9, 5, 12, 3, 8, 4, 8, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 8, 6, 8, 5, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1],
  },
}

//Generate the brush focus chart
generateMinimap(signalData.signal1.data);

//Generate charts dynamically as often as i have signals
for (var signal in this.signalData) {
  this.generateCharts(
    signalData[signal].data,
    signalData[signal].name
  );
}


function generateCharts(data, name) {
  var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 50
  };
  var width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, data.length]) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
    .range([height, 0]); // output

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
    .y((d) => yScale(d));

  var svg = d3
    .select("#" + name)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var brush = d3.brushX().extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width - margin.right, height],
  ]);

  svg.append("g").call(brush);
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

  svg
    .append("path")
    .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("d", line) // 11. Calls the line generator
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");
}

function generateMinimap(data) {
  var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 50,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 50
  };
  var width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
  var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, data.length]) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
    .range([height, 0]); // output

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
    .y((d) => yScale(d));

  var svg = d3
    .select("#minimap")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var brush = d3
    .brushX()
    .extent([
      [0, 0],
      [width - margin.right, height],
    ])
    .on("brush", brushed);

  svg.append("g").call(brush);

  function brushed(d) {
    return
  }

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

  svg
    .append("path")
    .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("d", line) // 11. Calls the line generator
    .attr("fill-opacity", "0.17")
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="minimap"></div>

<!-- 
  In the original project these divs are not 
  static and get generated with v-for as many times as 
  i have a signal in signalData
-->
<div id="signal1"></div>
<div id="signal2"></div>
<div id="signal3"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a few things:

1. Move all shared things outside the `generateChart` function, because they're shared between charts - so they cannot be local variables;
2. Create separate x-scales for the minimap and for the other charts. The one for the other charts will be affected by the brush;
3. Split the `generateChart` logic into a part that prepares everything that needs to be done only once, and logic that needs to be executed every time. Otherwise, you get one chart per call to `brush`, instead of a new chart that updates;
4. Create a function `brushed` that limits this x-scale, like any brush example, and then redraws the charts;

Note that the line overflows when you brush, you need to use a `clipPath` to keep that from happening, like I show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64730186/5015356).

You cannot filter the data, because as soon as you remove entries from the `data` array, the x location of the other points changes, because `i` is different.

```js
var signalData = {
  signal1: {
    name: "signal1",
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 5, 7, 4, 6],
  },
  signal2: {
    name: "signal2",
    data: [6, 4, 8, 5, 4, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 8, 7, 2, 9, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 0, 5, 7, 1],
  },
  signal3: {
    name: "signal3",
    data: [9, 5, 12, 3, 8, 4, 8, 6, 3, 4, 7, 8, 5, 2, 1, 8, 6, 8, 5, 8, 4, 8, 5, 1],
  },
}

var margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 40,
  left: 50
};
var width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(Object.keys(signalData), d => signalData[d].data.length)]) // input
  .range([0, width]); // output

var brushXScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(Object.keys(signalData), d => signalData[d].data.length)]) // input
  .range([0, width]); // output

var brush = d3.brushX().extent([
  [0, 0],
  [width - margin.right, height],
]).on("brush", brushed);

function brushed(d) {
  var selectionPx = d3.brushSelection(this); // === [lower, upper] in pixels
  
  // transform from pixels to x-values
  var selectionX = [xScale.invert(selectionPx[0]), xScale.invert(selectionPx[1])];
  
  // set x scale domain, then redraw the lines
  brushXScale.domain(selectionX);

  for (var signal in signalData) {
    updateChart(
      signalData[signal].data,
      signalData[signal].name
    );
  }
}

//Generate the brush focus chart
generateMinimap(signalData.signal1.data);
//Generate charts dynamically as often as i have signals
for (var signal in this.signalData) {
  generateChart(
    signalData[signal].data,
    signalData[signal].name
  );
}

// This function is for the one time preparations
function generateChart(data, name) {
  var svg = d3
    .select("#" + name)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

  svg
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");
  
  updateChart(data, name);
}

// This function needs to be called to update the already prepared chart
function updateChart(data, name) {
  var svg = d3.select("#" + name + " svg");

  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
    .range([height, 0]); // output

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d, i) => brushXScale(i))
    .y((d) => yScale(d));
  console.log(line([1, 2, 3, 4]));
  
  svg.select(".x.axis")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(brushXScale));

  svg.select(".y.axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  
  svg
    .select(".line")
    .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
    .attr("d", line) // 11. Calls the line generator
}

function generateMinimap(data) {
  var yScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)]) // input
    .range([height, 0]); // output

  var line = d3
    .line()
    .x((d, i) => xScale(i))
    .y((d) => yScale(d));

  var svg = d3
    .select("#minimap")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g").call(brush);

  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

  svg
    .append("path")
    .datum(data) // 10. Binds data to the line
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("d", line) // 11. Calls the line generator
    .attr("fill-opacity", "0.17")
    .attr("fill", "blue")
    .attr("stroke", "blue");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.js"></script>

<div id="minimap"></div>

<!-- 
  In the original project these divs are not 
  static and get generated with v-for as many times as 
  i have a signal in signalData
-->
<div id="signal1"></div>
<div id="signal2"></div>
<div id="signal3"></div>
```